# Evaluating logical expression which is represented as string in java

Tags: java

I am working on supporting notifications on kindle devices for our app. We will receive the expression sting from server which contains topics (topics will be in single quotes). We need to validate the expression by checking whether device is subscribed to the topics or not. Below is the example how logical expression looks like.

```
('18' in topics || '4' in topics) && ('REG_92779' in topics || 'REG_91212' in topics)
```

Assume the device is subscribed to topics '18' and '4' and not subscribed to other topics, the notification is not valid for the device. If the device is subscribed to topics '18' and 'REG_91212', the notification is valid for the device. I wrote the below code and it is working fine.

```
private boolean checkNotificationValid(String leString) {
        // Remove the 'in topics' string. examples of logical expression as below
        // ('4' in topics && '50000' in topics) || ('60' in topics || '3' in topics)
        // ('4' in topics && ('50000' in topics || '60' in topics))
        leString = leString.replaceAll("in topics", "");
        Log.d(TAG, "Logical Expression received : " + leString);
        boolean result = false;

        // Find the topics in the logical expression and check whether the device is subscribed to
        // the topic. If device is subscribed to the topic, replace the topic with 1 or replace the
        // topic with 0. Below is the example.
        // Assume device is subscribed to topics 3 and 4.
        // Expression : ('4' && '50000') || ('60' || '3')
        // After this block of code, it becomes : ('1' && '0') || ('0' || '1')
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(leString);
        while(m.find()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "LE : " + m.group(1));
            // Check whether the device is subscribed to the topic
            m.appendReplacement(buffer, NotificationUtils.isTopicExistInSharedPref(m.group(1)) ? "1" : "0");
        }

        m.appendTail(buffer);
        leString = buffer.toString();

        // Remove the quotes and spaces from the string, replace '||' with '|', replace '&&' with '&'
        // ('1' && '0') || ('0' || '1') -> (1&0)|(0|1)
        leString = leString.replaceAll("[' ]", "");
        leString = leString.replaceAll("\\|\\|", "|");
        leString = leString.replaceAll("&&", "&");
        Log.d(TAG, "String after changing : " + leString);

        // Evaluate the logical expression
        result = evaluateTopicExpression(leString);

        return result;
    }

    private boolean evaluateTopicExpression(String expString) {
        int len = expString.length();
        int idx = 0;
        boolean result = false;
        int parenCnt = 0;

        // Check for empty expression
        if(len == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "empty expression in evaluateTopicExpression");
            return false;
        }

        // If there is only one character it shouldn't be logical operator and shouldn't be
        // parentheses as we are removing parentheses while evaluating the expression.
        if(len == 1) {
            if(expString.charAt(idx) == '0') {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Check if the starting character is '('. If it is open parentheses, find the matching
        // closed parentheses. We need to find the exact closed parentheses, extract the string
        // between the parentheses and evaluate that string, concatenate the value to the remaining
        // string and evaluate the string.
        // Example as below.
        // (1|0)&(1&1) -> evaluate 1|0 -> result of 1|0 is 1 -> concatenate the result to remaining
        //                string -> 1&(1&1) -> evaluate the string
        // (1|0)&1 -> evaluate 1|0 -> result of 1|0 is 1 -> concatenate the result to remaining string
        //            -> 1&1 -> evaluate the string
        // (1&(0|1)) -> evaluate 1&(0|1) (This is because once we remove the last parentheses there
        //              is no remaining string after the parentheses)
        if(expString.charAt(idx) == '(') {
            int endIndex = 0;
            parenCnt ++;
            for(int i = idx + 1; i < len; i++) {
                if(expString.charAt(i) == '(') {
                    parenCnt++;
                } else if(expString.charAt(i) == ')') {
                    parenCnt--;
                }
                if(parenCnt == 0) {
                    endIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(parenCnt != 0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Invalid matching parentheses");
                return false;
            }

            if(endIndex == len - 1) {
                return evaluateTopicExpression(expString.substring(1, endIndex));
            }
            else {
                return evaluateTopicExpression((evaluateTopicExpression(expString.substring(1, endIndex)) ? '1' : '0')
                        + expString.substring(endIndex + 1));
            }
        }

        // If expression string length >= 2, evaluate the first 2 characters in the string and evaluate
        // the remaining string in the next recursive function call
        if(idx + 2 < len) {
            if(expString.charAt(idx + 1) == '|') {
                if(expString.charAt(idx) == '0') {
                    result = evaluateTopicExpression(expString.substring(idx + 2));
                } else {
                    result =  true;
                }
            }

            if(expString.charAt(idx + 1) == '&') {
                if(expString.charAt(idx) == '1') {
                    result = evaluateTopicExpression(expString.substring(idx + 2));
                } else {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error, Invalid logical expression");
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

checkNotificationValid() function replaces topics with 1 or 0 (based on whether device subscribed / not), trims the spaces, remove the quotes, replace '||' with '|', replace '&&' with '&' ... before sending the shortened string to evaluateTopicExpression().

For example, if the logical expression is

```
('18' in topics || '4' in topics) && ('REG_92779' in topics || 'REG_91212' in topics)
```

and the device is subscribed to topics '18', '4', 'REG_92779', checkNotificationValid() calls evaluateTopicExpression() with the below string

```
(1|1)&(1|0)
```

I tested with lot of expressions and the code is working fine. Even though code is working fine, I feel like evaluateTopicExpression() has lot of code and it is not efficient code as I am going through each character and calling the function recursively. Is there anyway we can reduce the code and evaluate the expression in more efficient way.

NOTE: Instead of replacing the code with 1 or 0, we can replace with true or false like

```
(true||true)&&(true||false)
```

All I need to do is whether the notification is valid for the device or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do the parsing an the evaluation in the same recursive function `boolean evalExpression(String expr)`. This way you can avoid recursion into redundant trees.
If you evaluate one half of a expression that has the && operator and it's false you don't need to evaluate the other half.

Comment: I am not sure with out recursive calls how we can sole this problem easily. I am already skipping the recursive calls if the operator is && and left side of the operator is false (in the same way if the operator is || and left side of the operator is true), I just gave one example which has && in the middle. There will be lot of expressions which might have '||' only, which might have 3 topics. The topic limit in the expression is 5 and the operators allowed other than topic names are &&, ||, (). We can form variety of expressions using these conditions.

Comment: The point being if you parse (validate) the expression before evaluating it then you are parsing expressions that may not need to be evaluated. When you say a limit of 5 is this per "sub" expression ie. `('18' in topics || '4' in topics || '5' in topics || '6' in topics || '7' in topics) && ('REG_92779' in topics || 'REG_91212' in topics)` is valid?

Comment: Got the unnecessary parsing part if I evaluate before parsing complete expression. Maximum limit is 5 per whole expression. I am basically looking for some thing along the lines of accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974402/evaluate-boolean-values-in-java. But unable to think how to do that. If I can do like that I can reduce lot of code in the evaluation function.

Comment: I think you could probably use the code in that answer, replacing the parse boolean with your evaluation of the topic. I would probably still make a recursive call for anything that's enclosed in parenthesis () to avoid complicating the code.